# I am looking for Product (computer systems specifically) datasets

Tags: data-request, products, computing

I am working on an expert system project and I am looking for sample data-sets for computer system products (laptops, desktops, tablets, etc.). This data should include at least price and specifications.

Do you know where I can find data which has this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you haven's specified a timeframe of the data you are looking for, you can try the amazon crawl: http://jmcauley.ucsd.edu/data/amazon/

Particularly:
metadata (3.1gb) - metadata for 9.4 million products

Where:

- asin - ID of the product, e.g. 0000031852
- title - name of the product
- price - price in US dollars (at time of crawl)
- imUrl - url of the product image
- related - related products (also bought, also viewed, bought together, buy after viewing)
- salesRank - sales rank information
- brand - brand name
- categories - list of categories the product belongs to

I suppose you can filter by category to get only laptops,desktops, tablets,etc..

Mind that the data is oldish: May 1996 - July 2014.

Comment: Is there such a list that is crawled from multiple sources?